# Ubuntu One for Xfce or Xubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-one, xubuntu, xfce, thunar

Is it possible to use [Ubuntu One](https://one.ubuntu.com/files/) with `Xfce`/`Xubuntu` without installing too many `GNOME` dependencies like `Nautilus`?

Answer (score 14):

In xubuntu 12.04 you can install `ubuntuone-client` and `ubuntuone-control-panel-qt`. Starting `ubuntuone-control-panel-qt` will then kick off the login and set up your synced folders and everything. Still no thunar integration, but the control panel has enough features that it makes using `u1sdtool` unnecessary.

For older versions, the previous answer below is probably still useful.

---

You don't need `ubuntuone-client-gnome` to use the file sync service of Ubuntu One on your desktop; you lose some integration, but you probably wouldn't appreciate that integration if you're on something other than GNOME anyway.

`u1sdtool` (part of [ubuntuone-client](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ubuntuone-client) [image: Install ubuntuone-client]) is a commandline program that talks to `ubuntuone-syncdaemon` over dbus, and allows you to do nearly everything you can do via the Nautilus plugin, and some things the Nautilus plugin doesn't know about yet. The only thing not implemented in `u1sdtool` is sharing a folder with somebody via email; the sharing functionality exported via `u1sdtool` is slightly arcane, and requires you to know the SSO username of the share receiver, and the share receiver to accept the share using `u1sdtool`; I'd recommend you use the sharing exposed via the web interface unless you're very confortable with the commandline. The functionality currently in the tool and not in Nautilus includes the ability of *unsubscribing* from (and resubscribing to) some of your synced folders.

Nobody has done the work to talk to the same dbus interfaces from Thunar (either directly or via `libsyncdaemon`), but it's certainly possible. Keep in mind that these interfaces sometimes change during development of an Ubuntu release, and while we try to notify other developers of upcoming changes, we make no promises. This communication issue has been the source of some significant frustration in the past, and we're working to address it, hopefully in time for 11.04.

Comment: Now this is what I call an answer. Thx, Chipaca !

Answer (score 9):

The Nautilus extension is provided by the package `ubuntuone-client-gnome`. So if you don't install that package, you shouldn't have to install Nautilus. I removed `ubuntuone-client-gnome` on my Ubuntu (gnome) system and Ubuntu One still works, there just isn't any integration with Nautilus, Rhythmbox etc.

Comment: Is it possible to use Thunar?

Comment: @burli I don't think anyone has made an U1 extension for Thunar.

Comment: Thunar will work with ubuntuone-client. There is no need to install or use nautilus

Answer (score 5):

Additionally, if you use the new ubuntuone-control-panel-qt on Precise, you can use the `--with-icon` option to replace the launcher you don't have on XFCE/LXDE

Comment: After I installed with Ubuntu Software Center I did what Jorge said, use ALT-F2 and then `ubuntuone-control-panel-qt --with-icon` and it works great.

Comment: Does this need to be started every time? E.g. `Settings` > `Session and Startup` > `Application Autostart` > New... > `sh -c 'ubuntuone-control-panel-qt --with-icon'`

Answer (score 5):

I've been able to find a workaround for the publishing function of the Ubuntu One client not available from the Thunar. I created a custom action for that. So, whenever I want to publish a file on the Internet, I move it to the `Ubuntu one` directory, right-click the file, and select the action. The command for the action is following: `u1sdtool --publish-file=%f | awk '{print $5}' | xclip -i -selection "clipboard"`. u1sdtool publishes the selected file the path to which is taken from the variable `%f` and returns the message containing file's URL e. g.:

> File is published at http://ubuntuone.com/SomeUniqueSequence.

The URL (being the fifth piece of the string) is picked by the `awk '{print $5}'` and placed in the clipboard by `xclip -i -selection "clipboard"` (you might have to install xclip first). Then it can be pasted by CTRL+V or the “Paste” command. Chipaca, thanks for telling about u1sdtool.