# Install Ubuntu One on *ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-one, desktop-environments

What packages do I require to install Ubuntu One on Ubuntu with other DEs? I can't use the regular Ubuntu on this seriously old desktop. I just need enough for the backend to function in the background and sync me files.

Xfce uses GTK+, so what package should I install for the frontend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re ubuntuone and xubuntu - sounds very similar to this question and answer: [Ubuntu One for Xfce or Xubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15710/ubuntu-one-for-xfce)

Its been tidied up in 11.04 so that you dont have to install all the Gnome dependencies and other Gnome files

To summarise - use Software Centre and search for "UbuntuOne".

If you want to use the terminal so that you are content to see all the additional packages being installed then

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk
```

This will install the main control panel & other services to allow you to sync with the UbuntuOne folder in your Home folder.

To launch the Control Centre - create a menu link to run /usr/bin/ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk

Comment: That question doesn't say anything about which packages to install to get U1 in the first place.

Comment: @Oxwivi: That control panel has a GUI...