# How can I run Ubuntu One on Xubuntu?

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one, sync, xubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu One for Xfce or Xubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15710/ubuntu-one-for-xfce-or-xubuntu)

I installed Ubuntu One on my Xubuntu oneiric, but when starting the program nothing happens. I do not see the control center. Any ideas?

Comment: what errors (if any) when you run `ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk` from a terminal session?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install these packages to make Ubuntu One working in Xubuntu 11.10:
(In synaptic, search: ubuntuone)

1. desktopcouch-ubuntuone
2. python-ubuntuone
3. python-ubuntuone-client
4. python-ubuntuone-control-panel
5. python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol
6. ubuntuone-client
7. ubuntuone-client-dbg
8. ubuntuone-client-gnome
9. ubuntuone-control-panel
10. ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk
11. ubuntuone-couch

Then restart the computer. This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can install **ubuntuone-client** and that should pull in all the necessary packages to do file sync. You do not want to install **ubuntuone-client-gnome**. That will pull in a lot of Gnome stuff, like Nautilus, that you do not want.

You will want to become familiar with the command line tool **u1sdtool**. You will use this tool to access all the features in a non-Gnome environment. [Here is a nice page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RomanYepishev/UbuntuOne/ClientControl) discussing the u1sdtool.

Also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15710/ubuntu-one-for-xfce) provides some more information.

Comment: I installed ubuntuone-client and I just got the installer which pulled in ubuntuone-client-gnome anyways. I removed both ubuntuone-client-gnome and nautilus but I forgot to get rid of the dependencies with autoremove. Will using autoremove on its own delete them?